# How to add huamn face detector in expo camera react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to add a human face detector in the expo camera react native? how can I add that feature to my camera? like the user can only snap if a human face is detected else an alert pop up? How can I use "FaceDetector" by the expo in react native frontend only? i am using the "expo camera" package for the camera

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { firebase } from '../../Storage/Firebase/config';

export default function CameraPage({ navigation }) {

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.front);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();

      if (!photo.cancelled) {
        const response = await fetch(photo.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const filename = photo.uri.substring(photo.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);
        const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
        const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(url)
        navigation.navigate('addpost', { post: url });
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={cameraRef}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              width: 90,
              height: 90,
              borderRadius: 500,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              marginTop: '150%',
              marginLeft: '35%',
              borderColor: '#fff',
              borderWidth: 4,
            }}
            onPress={handleTakePicture}
          >
            <View style={{ opacity: 0.5, }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You have 3 approaches to the problem (ordered by simplicity): You could you an API(firebase offers one), you could use a backend that uses AI(face-detection <-- npm) and returns the results or you could use tensorflow.js, load the AI on the client and make use of it.

Comment: If you want I can make this more elaborate and write it out as an answer. Good luck

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer i want to do everything in frontend itself any idea about it?

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer What is the easy way to do that in my component in the frontend only,  i not have any idea about ai

Comment: Then your only option is to use an AI. While there are services, they are mostly freemiums. The max I can do is suggest for you to go though this 2 articles.
> https://recfaces.com/articles/face-recognition-apis
> https://rapidapi.com/blog/top-facial-recognition-apis/

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer Yep Can you make an ai human face detector using my code? so that i can just copy-paste paste i never use ai so it would be much helpful i tried to use expo-face-detector but it got many errors or if you can help me with backend i can use backend for face detector